# Why I'm having errors after install an update from 2.1.0 to 2.1.2 with composer?

Tags: magento2, error, upgrade, composer

Errors after installing update from 2.1.0 to 2.1.2

```
 PHP Warning: 
 require(/var/www/vendor/composer/../../app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php):
 failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
 /var/www/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71 PHP Fatal error:
 require(): Failed opening required
 '/var/www/vendor/composer/../../app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php'
 (include_path='/var/www/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:/var/www/vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator:/var/www/vendor/phpunit/phpunit:/var/www/vendor/symfony/yaml:.:/usr/share/php')
 in /var/www/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 71
```

I have removed the cache, completely removed vendor dir and reinstalled via composer install.  Doesn't matter what I do, I cannot get past this error.

Answer (score 6):

Check if doesn't have 2.1.0 in your **composer.json**, so run these commands:

```
rm -rf vendor/*
composer install && composer update -vvv
```

Answer (score 1):

In root directory have a file composer.json, inner this file exists this code line

```
"require": {
        "intelipost/magento2-basic": "^1.2",
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.3.1"
    },
```

Remove modules that you will not use, use command line bellow

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, had to do with user permissions and writing the file to app/etc....

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error on the Magento Cloud. 
What worked for me is to set the app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php permissions to 666, then re-run the Cloud build by committing and pushing:

```
chmod 666 app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php
git add --force app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php
git commit -m "Fixed NonComposerComponentRegistration.php permissions"
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Reference: https://www.mexbs.com/magento-blog/developing-on-the-magento-cloud-a-step-by-step-tutorial/

Answer (score -1):

Please remove files from var folder using command

```
cd var
rm -rf *
```

now move to root directory of magento and run deploy command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

after deploy provide permission to var folder and pub folder with 755 using command

```
chmod -R 755 pub var
```